# How do I display a node in a block?

Tags: nodes, 8, blocks

I would like to display a node as a block in Drupal 8, but I don't know how to do this. I know in Drupal 7 I could use the Nodeblock module to accomplish this task, but there isn't a Drupal 8 version of it (and it looks like that there never will be).

Can this be accomplished using another module that I am not aware of?

Comment: Create a view of content items. Filter by the node. Make a block display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a file to your module at `src/Plugin/Block/YourBlock.php`

```
namespace Drupal\your_module\Plugin\Block;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Provides a block.
 * @Block(
 *   id = "your_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("YourBlock")
 * )
 */
class YourBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {

    $nid = 2;
    $entity_type = 'node';
    $view_mode = 'teaser';

    $view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder($entity_type);
    $storage = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage($entity_type);
    $node = $storage->load($nid);
    $build = $view_builder->view($node, $view_mode);

    return $build;

  }

  ...
```

I'm sure with a little effort you can continue this by using blockForm, blockSubmit to set the node id/type/view_mode etc.

Comment: Thanks, this looks pretty straight forward to implement. I am surprised no one has created a module for this already.

Comment: @user5013 `I am surprised no one has created a module for this already.` It's called Views.

Comment: @NoSssweat Yes you can do it in views, but it is not very user friendly for site editors to use (and gives them too much power). I am looking for something that allow site editors to use easily.

Comment: Here is detailed tutorial for developing a "nodeblock" like module for Drupal 8 : https://www.sitepoint.com/tutorial-on-using-drupal-8-plugin-derivatives-effectively/

Answer (score 0):

There's a module for that now: [Quick Node Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/quick_node_block). \m/